# Not Receiving email since changing Nameservers

Tags: email, heroku, dns, nameservers, mx-record

I changed the nameservers of a domain I am using about 2 hours ago and since then don't seem to be receiving emails correctly.

My domain was bought at Fasthosts and the nameservers are now configured to use Zerigo DNS (this was setup through Fasthost manage Nameservers interface). I also have Fasthosts configured with Google MX records to allow Google to run my email but since changing the nameservers seem unable to receive emails.

Do I need to be setting up additional MX records in Zerigo as I changed my nameservers from Fasthosts to Zerigos?

If so does anyone know how I can setup MX records in Zerigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MX records are just another type of record along with A records or CNAMEs that you've setup for your website.

If you have moved your name servers from fasthosts to Zerigo then you must also add your MX records to Zerigo too.

In order to add a record to Zerigo, open the addon using `$ heroku addons open zerigo`. Then you should click configure to get to the Zerigo panel. From here make sure you're on the hosts page and click add. Change type to MX and set the priority and data to match each entry in the list of Google MX server. Repeating for each Google server.

The list of Google mail server is [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174125&topic=2683820&ctx=topic).

Comment: Thanks for this Steve, managed to get it all working as a result :)